# Can Java exception safety be made less ugly?

Tags: java, raii, exception-safety

Given the following code: We need to lock the model, then start a transaction (which could throw an exception so we have to make sure the lock is released), then do something kind of like getting a database connection (which could throw an exception), then do some stuff which could throw an exception requiring the transaction to be reverted.  This is Java 6 so we don't have Java 7 good stuff available.

```
SomeClass someMethod() 
throws SomeException {
  acquireWriteLock();
  try {
    startTransaction();
    try {
      DBConnection d = openDBConnection();
      try {
        doStuff(d);
        commitTransaction();
      } finally {
        d.close();
      }
    } catch (SomeException e) {
      handleSomeException(e);
      revertTransaction();
      throw e;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      revertTransaction();  // Error: method must return a value of SomeClass
    }
  } finally {
    releaseWriteLock();
  }
}
```

Can this be rewritten to be more readable and less verbose?

Just for fun: when you see the following, what do you do about it?

```
DBConnection d = null;
try {
  acquireWriteLock();
  startTransaction();
  d = openDBConnection();
  try {
    doStuff(d);
    commitTransaction();
  } catch (SomeException e) {
    handleSomeException(e);
    revertTransaction();
  }
} finally {
  d.close();
  releaseWriteLock();
}
```

Comment: There's not much you can do unless you upgrade to Java 7.

Comment: Doesn't your first code block close the dtb connection before the transaction could have been reverted in the case of an Exception? In that regard, I think the second code block looks nicer and is safer. Or did I miss anything?

Comment: To tell you the truth, rather than upgrade to Java 7 I'd rather redo the whole thing in Erlang using shared-nothing communicating sequential processes and never have to worry about thread-safety again.  But that's not going to happen either.

Comment: Method names have been changed for reasons having to do with proprietary information; it's not really a DBConnection at all, so sorry to mislead people into thinking the problem can be easily solved by having the database handle the transactions.

Comment: @MarkLutton Right. Still, I'm going to be the curious one. If you had a free minute or two, could you please explain to me why is the first block preferred over the second one? Is it because `openDBConnection()` could throw something meaningful that would have to be taken care of? If that is the case, it could be just pushed one line down in the second block and it would be the same. It's mind boggling for me, I'm just trying to get it :).

Comment: It's Java - the reality is it's pretty much destined to be horrifically verbose because of that.

Comment: With regard to the second block of code, if acquireWriteLock() or startTransaction() throws an exception then d.close() will throw a null pointer exception.  If acqireWriteLock() does not throw an exception but startTransaction() does, then d.close() will throw, and the lock will never be released.  Additionally, any exception other than SomeException() will leave the transaction open.  Just about any code can throw an OutOfMemoryException, for instance if a coding error makes doStuff() go into infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch to Java 7 you can simplify it a lot.  Otherwise, there's probably not much you *should* do about it.

You *could* try ideas like:

- refactor the DB connection + transaction management + lock management into a general method in a common baseclass, with a subclass for each transaction type
- refactor the DB connection + transaction management + lock management into a general method in a final class, with an interface for transaction types and an implementation class for each one.

However, unless this particular pattern is repeated many, many times, this kind of refactoring is probably a bad idea.  (You'd be creating a local idiom, and the reader has to learn the idiom before the meaning becomes clear.)

Comment: What's so bad about local idioms? As soon as this pattern occurs a few times I would say it is worth to encapsulate the behavior. Only _PITA_ in Java is the absence of first class functions, so it's necessary to struggle with OOP shenanigans.

Answer (score 1):

Without upgrading to Java 7 you can combine some of this so you only need a single try-catch.

```
SomeClass someMethod() throws SomeException {
   boolean committed = false;
   DBConnection d = null;
   acquireWriteLock();
   try {
      startTransaction();
      d = openDBConnection();
      doStuff(d);
      commitTransaction();
      committed = true;
   } catch (SomeException e) {
      handleSomeException(e);
      throw e;
   } finally {
     if( d != null ) d.close();
     if( !committed ) revertTransaction();
     releaseWriteLock();
   }
}
```

The trick is to make sure revertTransaction() and DBConnection.close() don't throw anything, but if you can't do that then you can put releaseWriteLock() in another finally clause.  If you really wanted to improve this more you could do some of the refactorings Stephen C mentioned.  Doing something like putting the acquire/release writeLock, start/rollback transaction, and open/close DBConnection are done in base class or some abstract operation class.

Comment: I wouldn't refactor like this.  You've got fewer lines of code, but those lines require a closer reading to verify correctness.

Comment: Well I suppose it's a matter of taste as I see this is much easier on the eyes by reducing the 3 nested try-catch-finally statements into a single try-catch-finally.  In the end both have to be verified closely.  But, this moves all clean up to the bottom of the code and out of the main flow of the code which is what exceptions were originally introduced to do as in separate the error handling code away from the control flow of the logic.

Comment: Lambda expressions would be nice.  writeLockWrap(new Runnable(){public void run(){do.stuff();}}, new Runnable(){public void run(){/* finally code goes here */}});

Comment: Indeed.  But until the closure syntax can be added (Java 8) we're stuck with anonymous inner classes + interface or abstract class.  Which isn't that bad and equivalent in expressiveness to lambdas, but a little annoying in terms of code size.  A simple one might be new DBoperation() { public Object execute(DBConnection db) { return doStuff( db ); } }.run();